# Execute 2 or more remote scripts sharing the same curl pattern, without redundancy

Tags: shell-script, pipe, wildcards, curl, for

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I execute a list of remote scripts that are in the same directory (a GitHub repository):

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${user}/${repo}/master/1.sh | tr -d '\r' | bash
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${user}/${repo}/master/2.sh | tr -d '\r' | bash
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${user}/${repo}/master/3.sh | tr -d '\r' | bash
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${user}/${repo}/master/4.sh | tr -d '\r' | bash
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${user}/${repo}/master/5.sh | tr -d '\r' | bash
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${user}/${repo}/master/6.sh | tr -d '\r' | bash
```

How would you cope with the awful redundancy?

I think of a `for` loop but I have no idea how to construct it. All `for` loops I've seen so far doesn't give me a clue on how to do that particular task of reusing a `curl` pattern (and piped output) for different files in the same remote directory.

You are more than welcome to share an example.

### Update

- There might be more or less than six such `curl` operations.
- I would use any plausible way but if it requires a utility please recommend a utility available in the Debian repositories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For two or more files you could use [Unix seq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seq_(Unix)):

```
for var in $(seq 6)
   do 
       curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${user}/${repo}/master/$var.sh | tr -d '\r' | bash
   done
```

**Explanation:**

1. Use the output of `seq` to attain a count up to 6 (as the question lists 6 `curl` operations).
2. Read the output into the variable `var` and use this in your `curl` command.

Comment: double quote your variables when you use them - `$user` or `$repo` could contain spaces, tabs, or shell metacharacters.  In this case, just double-quote the entire URL string: `curl -s "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${user}/${repo}/master/$var.sh" | tr ...`

Comment: Is the `seq 6` an upper border? I could put it to say 10 if I had a **range** of 1-10 files?

Comment: Yes, you can change it to what ever you want

Comment: Sure, just wanted to ensure it's a matter of range and not fixed number. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The fastest one with GNU **`parallel`**:

```
parallel -j0 -k "curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${user}/${repo}/master/{1}.sh \
                 | tr -d '\r' | bash" ::: {1..6}
```

---

You may also specify the crucial number via dynamic variable:

```
n=7
parallel -j0 -k "curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${user}/${repo}/master/{1}.sh \
                 | tr -d '\r' | bash" ::: $(seq $n)
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html