# GitHub repeatedly changes all leads from spaces to tabs and remote script executions (curl) fail

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, curl, github

By design, GitHub automatically converts all leads from tabs to spaces when you re-edit a file with leading tabs: That is, if you edit a file, changing all leads from spaces to tabs, it will be saved this way, but if you re-edit the file and save (without changing leads), all leads will be automatically converted back to spaces.

**1)** File edit mode before saving the changes:

[image]

**2)** File edit after saving the changes:

[image]

Note how it went back from tabs (4), to spaces (2), just when I came to re-edit the file.

---

### Why that's a problem

Execution of **raw** versions of remote scripts with `curl`, containing **tab-dependent** data (like [here-documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)), will fail. Their execution will just break with some error because they must contain leading tabs and not spaces.

That's the basic `curl` pattern I use to execute remote scripts from GitHub is the following (<sub>For multiple curl, [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423034/273994).</sub>):

```
curl -s URL | tr -d '\r' | bash
```

### My question

Is there a way (probably with `tr`) to change all leading spaces into tabs, to make sure that remote scripts I run from GitHub will always have leading tabs instead spaces, thus not effected by this strange behavior of GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say much about GitHub and its editor as I never edit GitHub files directly in the web interface.

The standard utilities [`expand`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/expand.html) and [`unexpand`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/unexpand.html) may be used to convert leading tabs into spaces (`expand`) or leading spaces into tabs (`unexpand`).

To change the leading two spaces into a tab (or four spaces into two tabs etc.), use

```
unexpand -t 2 file
```

This can also be used as a filter as in

```
somecommand | unexpand -t 2
```

To replace any number of leading spaces with a single tab, one could also use GNU `sed` like so:

```
sed 's/^  */\t/'
```

The pattern is `^  *` with *two* spaces between the `^` and the `*`.  This regular expression will match one or more leading spaces (equivalent of `^ +` or `^ {1,}` if using GNU `sed` with `-r` or `-E`).  The GNU `sed` substitution will replace these with a tab (other implementations of `sed` will need a literal tab character in the replacement part, instead of `\t`).

---

I'm noticing that this will not work on OpenBSD as its implementation of `unexpand` assumes eight spaces per tab and won't recognize the `-t` flag. The above suggestion works with `unexpand` as found in GNU coreutils though.

Comment: I just read `man unexpand`: `unexpand -t 2 --first-only file` is what I need! Thanks! But small note - some files have 2/4/6/8 tabs. Is there a wildcard to gather all? Can regex be added somehow?

Comment: @user9303970 See updated answer.

Comment: @user9303970 As far as I know, `--first-only` will only be needed to negate the effect of an earlier `--all` (`-a`) flag.